# How to pass Bitmap to the android Worker?

Tags: android, background-process

I have to compress the bitmap in the background. The bitmap compression code in written in Worker. I want to pass the Bitmap which has to be cropped to the Worker. I went through all the available resources online but did not find any solution.

How to pass the Bitmap to the Worker?

Please help

**Thank you**

Comment: what `Worker` object do you mean? if it is `WorkManager` then use `setInputData`

Comment: Use coroutines instead of work and get results back in the main UI thread after. You can do the same compression in the main thread using Dispatchers.Default i.e. in background.

Comment: You need to pass image uri instead of the Bitmap itself. Look at this codelab, it has got everything that you need to know: https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/android-workmanager-kt/

Comment: @pskink can you please elaborate how to use `setInputData`

Answer (score 0):

Instead of passing the whole bitmap, Save it in your app and get the path to it, and send the path to the worker via input data

```
    val builder = OneTimeWorkRequestBuilder<YOURWORKER>()
    val myData = Data.Builder()
                        .putString(Constants.WORKER_THREAD_PARAM_FILE, imagePath)
                        .build()
    builder.setInputData(myData)
    WorkManager.getInstance().enqueue(builder.build())
```

get path in your worker

```
val imagePath = params.inputData.getString(Constants.WORKER_THREAD_PARAM_FILE)
```

Comment: thanks for the answer, but i want to pass the Bitmap only, that what i have. I dont have its URL.

Comment: path means local path , not url

Comment: i dont have the local path either. What i have have is only Bitmap.